# CSS border not fitting item right

Tags: html, css, border

i have a page at [this link](http://truefoodlooks.com/compare.php?id=49) and im trying to get the border around the comments to not be higher than the bottom of the image so i have this for the html of one of the comments:

```
<li class="comment-item">
    <a name="comment-94"></a>
    <div class="comment-buttons">
        <a href="javascript:report(94);" class="report">Report</a>
        <a href="javascript:add_vote(94);" class="vote" id="vote-94">+1</a>
        <a href="?id=49&amp;replytocom=94#respond" class="reply">Reply</a>
    </div>
    <img src="/images/avatars/default.png" height="85" width="100">
    <p class="user">nat45928</p>
    <p class="date">August 3, 2011, 5:04 am</p>
    <p class="comment-body">test</p>
</li>
```

and i have this for the css associoated with the comment item:

```
.comments .comment-item {
    list-style: none;
    border:2px black solid;
    border-radius:15px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    clear:both;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}

.comments .comment-item * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.comments .comment-item .user {
    font-family: "True Food Looks";
    letter-spacing:-2px;
    display:inline;
}

.comments .comment-item .date {
    margin-left:10px;
    display:inline;
}

.comments .comment-item img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.comments .comment-item .comment-buttons {
    float:right;
    display:block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 70px;
}

.comments .comment-item .comment-buttons a {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.comments .comment-item .comment-buttons .report {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color:#C6B784;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px 20px;
}

.comments .comment-item .comment-buttons .vote {
    height: 20px;
    background-color:#70675C;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.comments .comment-item .comment-buttons .reply {
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color:#C6B784;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px 15px;
}
```

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.comment-item:before, .comment-item:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.comment-item:after { clear: both; }
.comment-item { zoom: 1; }
```

[Here is the example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0J)

Comment: This is a pretty common technique for wrapping floated elements. Should be applied on the floated elements' containers in order for them to wrap the floated elements. This is needed because once you float an element it is not a part of the normal flow anymore and the container doesn't know where the element is ending and just ignores it, wrapping the rest of the content only.

Answer (score 1):

Add for content-item (your LI)

```
min-height:95px;
```

before your closing `</li>`

add:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a div below each `.comment-body <p>` like this:

```
<li class="comment-item">
    <a name="comment-93"></a>
    <div class="comment-buttons">
        <a href="javascript:report(93);" class="report">Report</a>
        <a href="javascript:add_vote(93);" class="vote" id="vote-93">+0</a>
        <a href="?id=49&replytocom=93#respond" class="reply">Reply</a>
</div>

    <img src="/images/avatars/default.png" width="100" height="85" />
    <p class="user">nat45928</p>
    <p class="date">August 3, 2011, 5:04 am</p>
    <p class="comment-body">test</p>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Won't that push the comment body under the image?

Comment: Arf… non-semantic markup that generates a gap in IE? Don't think it's nice.

Comment: @splitter - line-height and font-size to 0 will fix the gap, but not the extra div :)